# Within a window function how to refer back to the column that is being defined, namely reference to itself?

Tags: sqlite, window-functions

In order to calculate adjusted cost base (ACB), it's a running sum of either Price * Quantity + Commission, or Previous ACB/Share * Quantity, depending on whether it's a sale or a purchase.

I have the following table, named `transaction_t`:

| Date | Action | Quantity | Price | Commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-02 | buy | 150 | 110.21 | 5.95 |
| 2021-01-21 | buy | 360 | 106.87 | 5.95 |
| 2021-03-21 | sell | 360 | 106.87 | 5.95 |

For calculating a running "adjusted cost base", I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE 
        WHEN T.Action in ("buy", "reinvest") THEN T.Quantity
        ​WHEN Action = "sell" THEN -T.Quantity
      END
  ) OVER (ORDER BY T.Date) AS quantity_balance,
  SUM(CASE 
        WHEN T.Action in ("buy", "reinvest") THEN T.Quantity * T.Price + T.Commission
        WHEN T.Action = "sell" THEN T.Quantity * ***(previous_total_acb / previous_quantity_balance)***[1]
      END
  ) OVER (ORDER BY T.Date) AS total_acb
  FROM transaction_t AS T;
```

This query doesn't work. Because the pseudo code `previous_total_acb / previous_quantity_balance` are refering to the column that are being defined in that window function.

How to make this work in SQLite?

Note [1]: Here the `previous_total_acb` is a pseuoudo code, I intend it to refer to the column itself, the `total_acb`. But sqlite doesn't seem to support such looping-back reference.
The `previous_quantity_balance` is referring to the sibling column that is also created by a window function, the `quantity_balance`. This doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Edit your question and explain what is previous_total_acb and previous_quantity_balance, better with sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a CTE (or subquery) to prepare your lookback calculations, and then reference them in your final query.
I don't understand your actual sql. Here is a simplified version that might not make sense but simply demonstrates the structure:

This first CTE is just to give some values, which in your case comes from your table:

```
WITH TBL(d, a, q, p)
AS
(
   SELECT * FROM (
              VALUES (20210102, 'buy',  150, 110.21),
                     (20210121, 'buy',  380, 106.87),
                     (20210321, 'sell', 360, 104.33)
                 )
),
```

so in reality you would start here with `WITH`

```
SRC AS
(
    SELECT d,
           a,
           q,
           p,
           q*p AS cost,
           lag(q*p) OVER (ORDER BY d) AS prev_cost
      FROM TBL
)
```

Which yields this:

```
+--------+----+---+------+-------+---------+
|d       |a   |q  |p     |cost   |prev_cost|
+--------+----+---+------+-------+---------+
|20210102|buy |150|110.21|16531.5|NULL     |
|20210121|buy |380|106.87|40610.6|16531.5  |
|20210321|sell|360|104.33|37558.8|40610.6  |
+--------+----+---+------+-------+---------+
```

and from there you could use the current and previous values to produce a calculated field

```
SELECT d, cost, cost-prev_cost AS diff FROM SRC ORDER BY d;
```

which (as I said is just for demonstration and has no real meaning here) yields

```
+--------+-------+----------+
|d       |cost   |diff      |
+--------+-------+----------+
|20210102|16531.5|NULL      |
|20210121|40610.6|24079.1   |
|20210321|37558.8|-3051.79  |
+--------+-------+----------+
```

So putting that together and assuming your data is stored in `TBL` it would look like

```
WITH SRC AS
(
    SELECT d,
           a,
           q,
           p,
           q*p AS cost,
           lag(q*p) OVER (ORDER BY d) AS prev_cost
      FROM TBL
)
SELECT d, cost, cost-prev_cost AS diff FROM SRC ORDER BY d;
```

You can have as many CTE's as needed to prep your 'lookback' data. Not sure, but seems you might need at least one more middle prep CTE in your case to calculate `previous_total_acb` before you can use it in your final query.

Comment: This is pretty info-dense but I believe this is the right direction.

Comment: Is there a reason why choose CTE over subqueries?

Comment: @JinghuiNiu  Subquery should work just fine. Was not meant to sound dogmatic. CTE's lend some readability and can be referenced by other CTE's, but so can subqueries if written correctly. In your case, if you were required to nest subqueries (not sure if you need to but possibly) the CTE's would be a bit easier to read.